# computing the fundamental group of a wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to solve the problem $18 (a$ from the chapter $1$ of Hatcher's Algebraic topology.
it is:

Prove that the wedge sum $S^1 \vee S^2$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$.

The next chapter is about Van Kampen,I don't know how to prove it without that.

Comment: Consider a loop, you can assume that it doesn't hit some particular point in $S^2$. Now $S^2$ minus a point is a disc, hence you can homotope your loop so that it lies entirely in $S^1$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If we have a loop completely in $S^2$,as you said it is ok. But what if a part of the loop was in $S^2$ and a part in $S^1$?

Comment: No I mean, for *any* loop you can take the part in $S^2$ down to the wedge point. Hence you get a loop that lies in $S^1$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier yes.right.but how to write it precisely?

Comment: There are three things: 1 you can avoid a point, 2 the sphere minus a point is a disc, 3 a disc is contractible. Which of these is unclear?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, your argument shows any loop is homotopic to a loop in $S^1$, but it doesn't quite show that the fundamental group is $\mathbb Z$. You would at least need to argue that the sphere does not allow new homotopies between existing loops in $S^1$ to be created.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip absolutely. That was not meant as an answer, just a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Construct its universal cover. To this end let $X$ be the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with a copy $S^2_{(k)}$ of of the 2-sphere attached at each integer $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

The space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the infinite wedge sum $\bigvee_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} S^2_{(k)}$, so is simply connected. The homotopy equivalence comes by just contracting each interval $[a,a+1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to a point. We can see its simply connected because it has a cellular structure in which the 1-skeleton is a single point.

Now $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $X$ as follows. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$ we let $t\cdot n=t+n$, and for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x_{(k)}\in S^2_{(k)}$ we let $x_{(k)}\cdot n=x_{(k+n)}\in S^2_{(k+n)}$. Observe that this is well defined, and moreover that it is free.

Now for the quotient we have a homeomorphism $X/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1\vee S^2$. To see this, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we send the coset $t\cdot\mathbb{Z}$ to $exp(2\pi i t)\in S^1\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^2$. For $x_{(k)}\in S^2_{(k)}$ we send the coset $x_{(k)}\cdot \mathbb{Z}$ to $x\in S^2\hookrightarrow S^1\vee S^2$. It should be clear that this is well defined and continuously invertible.

Hence we have a simply connected space $X$ with free right $\mathbb{Z}$ action, whose quotient is $S^1\vee S^2$. By the uniqueness of universal covers we  conclude that $X$ is the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^2$, and moreover that $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm new to algebraic topology and i know nothing of universal cover.

Comment: Then, firstly, welcome to the club. Don't worry, Hatcher will detail covering spaces soon enough (section 1.3). I though the question had come from this section.

Comment: Now I've looked up the question, it should be clear how to proceed using the suggested Lemma 1.15. Write each sphere as a union of its hemisphere discs, $S^1=D^1_+\cup D^1_-$ and $S^2=D^2_+\cup D^2_-$, and assume that basepoints have been fixed in each space that are contained in the interior of the positive disc $D^n_+$. Then $S^1\vee S^2$ is covered by the path connected open subsets $S^1\vee int(D^2_+)$ and $int(D^1_+)\vee S^2$. Check the intersection is path connected and apply the Lemma to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: You have reduced the computation of the fundamental group of a wedge sum of two spaces ---which the OP cannot do--- to the computation of the fundamental group of a countable wedge of spaces :-)

Comment: I did think that, but the argument that it's the suspension of $\bigvee S^1$ should be an understandable argument for simply contentedness.

Comment: You should probably add details (the argument depending on the CW decomposition with no 1-arcs depends on knowing how to compute fundamental groups of CW complexes using the 2-skeleton, which depends on van Kampen theorem, no?)

Comment: I should probably just delete the whole answer which sadly wasn't useful to the OP. If I did so, however, the whole internet would lose the "simply contentedness" typo from my last comment.